# Azure - best option for small data storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am new to Azure development. I am working on a ASP.Net core application and planning to host on Azure. This application requires a datastore to record oAuth credentials of all registered tenants. The data would be <10K rows.  What is the best option to store such data on Azure.

Comment: Does it matter? I ask because the libraries I use for this use case on the backend DEMAND the use of EntityFramework Core, which rules out all but 2 of the options on azure.

Comment: Thanks for response.  I understand, we can use Entity F/W so that code is independent of back-end datastore.  My question is more about, which one is a better service to purchase for this kind of data.

Comment: It is not that you CAN use it - most oauth libraries that I know use it OR you write a lot of code.

Comment: Hmmm... Azure is good but they are expensive. If you are new and only host small website, I believe that shared hosting should be enough. I would recommend you to check Asphostportal for .net hosting.